# How to set image to an image button

Tags: android, image, libgdx

I have taken an image button with the following code:

```
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("glassy-ui.json"));
        button2 = new ImageButton(skin);
        myTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("PlayButton.png"));
        myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(myTexture);
        myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
        button2.getStyle().imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("PlayButton.png"))));
        button2.addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                game.dispose();
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
                return true;
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(button2);
```

I want to set image in imagebutton as drawable,Refer this [link](https://libgdx.info/buttons-scene2d/) for further understanding . How can I do that? What I also want to do is that there is any visible reaction to an users input like changing its size etc..

By the way, the image is round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageButtonStyle imgBtnStyle=new ImageButtonStyle();
        imgBtnStyle.imageUp=new SpriteDrawable(spriteUp);
        imgBtnStyle.imageDown=new SpriteDrawable(spriteDown);
        ImageButton imgBtn=new ImageButton(imgBtnStyle);
```

Add Image button to stage. Do whatever animation(actions) you want to do, on this ImageButton Actor.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image in imagebutton like,

then try this

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
yourimagebutton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This is in xml, isnt´t it? But I want to do it in my MenuScreen class.

Comment: the question is for libgdx

Answer (score 0):

To fill the image in button, set Scale type FitXY.

`button2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

or To put the image in center of the button, set Scale type FitCenter.

`button2.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);`